# Setup Cloudmin on Centos installed in LVM

Tags: partition, lvm, kvm, virtualization, disk

I installed CentOS 6 with default LVM partition pattern. according to this pattern Can I use Cloudmin and store KVM Disks in LVM as Logical Volume? I think Cloudmin requires creating new logical volumes.

Comment: [Also posted on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/443625/setup-cloadmin-on-centos-installed-in-lvm). Please [do not post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073).